# Nested interface Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

A simple question, how to have a nested interface with this kind of json?

Thanks in advance.

**json**

```
"toto": {
 "toto1": [],
 "toto2": [],
 "toto3": [],
}
```

**interface** // here is my interface

```
export interface Itoto{
   code: {
    codeName: 
   } 
}
```

Comment: You mean `interface ItotoCode{ codeName:string;} interface Itoto{code: ItotoCode;}`?

Comment: how can I loop on it with your code? @AlirezaAhmadi

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
export interface Test {
    [key: string]: { // code
        [key: string]: string[] // codeName
    }
}

const test: Test = {
    "toto": {
        "toto1": [],
        "toto2": [],
        "toto3": [],
    }
};
```

To iterate over the test Object:

```
for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(test)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```